# Deploying to server via GitHub Actions and appleboy/scp-action fails with Tar short read error

Tags: github-actions, scp

I'm setting up an Express.js website that uses e.js as its rendering engine. I've been using a successful deployment script that has worked for me on many Node related projects, however this will be the first time I am using it to deploy Express and its related files. Be this as it may, these files can include `.js` files, `.png` files, `.ejs` files, so on and so forth, however, when I attempt to deploy, all works well except appleboys' scp-action tool. The current setup deploys the files using checkout which succeeds, however, when it gets to the tarring step, it immediately fails and does not continue.

**The deployment script**

```yaml
name: Deploy to Production
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Deploy Files to server
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@v0.1.4
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_IP }}
          username: ${{ secrets.DPLY_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DPLY_PWD }}
          overwrite: false
          source: "/*"
          target: ${{ secrets.PROJECT_PATH }}
      - name: Update Server-Side Scripts
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_IP }}
          username: ${{ secrets.DPLY_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DPLY_PWD }}
          script: |
            cd ${{ secrets.MAIN_PROJECT_PATH }}
            npm install
            pm2 restart 1
```

**The error that occurs when running**
[image: ERROR DESCRIPTION]

So I know that short read error means the file is corrupted, but I'm not sure why the file is suddenly corrupted, or how to prevent it. There are no corrupted files within the project. I have a feeling it is because the .ejs files are not exactly a real file type, but I am unsure how to do this otherwise.

Any help or other suggestions on how to do this would be great, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you that `source` should be `/*` and not your current directory only?

Comment: Yes. It’s in a GitHub actions runner so there’s nothing on there but the files from the repository

Comment: Seems like it should be `./*` to represent the current checked out repo. `/*` should result in everything in `/` (root directory). You might want to verify that.

Comment: I’ll definitely give it a try. I’ve used that in other actions and it’s worked but it’s worth the shot for sure

Comment: That was indeed not the solution -- just fails again with the same error.

Comment: Are you able to scp the same repo from your local machine? Also, have you verified that those secrets are correct i.e. `DEPLOY_IP`, `DPLY_USER`, `DPLY_PWD` (O in DEPLOY is missing for USER and PWD).

Comment: The secrets are correct -- I just got it to work somehow but I'm not really sure how. Then the second deploy it failed with a no permission error error:  tar: .git/objects/44/9eff5a58db26226d218f3be202536dd01d52af: Cannot open: Permission denied

Comment: You can exclude the `.git` directory i.e. `source: "./*,!.git"`.

Comment: Got it, this worked. Just trying to figure out why npm install is taking 3 minutes now lol thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe, you can use cache for that. I believe you can figure that out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved by correcting the source directory to `./*` instead of `/*`

*credits to @Azeem*